# Android Licensing - Only one public key per Android Developer account?

Tags: android, android-lvl

If my understanding of the Android LVL is correct, you get one public key per developer account.  What if I want to upload 2 paid apps through a single developer account?  There is no way to get a separate key for each app?  Consider this scenario:

-The user acquires a license by purchasing app "A" through the market.

-The user then downloads an unlicensed copy of app "B" through some other source.

Since the user had already purchased a license with app "A," will app "B" be seen as verified through LVL?

Forgive me if this has been explained somewhere else, but developer.android.com specifically states:

> Note that the test response that you configure applies account-wide — that is, it applies not to a single application, but to all applications associated with the publisher account. If you are testing multiple applications at once, changing the test response will affect all of those applications on their next license check (if the user is signed into the emulator or device using the publisher account or a test account).

This is what brought me to thinking about my theory.  Can anyone with experience concerning the Android LVL shed some light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to identify yourself, so it is tied to your account.  Each app you upload to the account is different (uniquely identified by its android manifest package name), and thus a different item the user buys and owns.  If that wasn't the case, then each developer could only charge once for all of their apps, and clearly that is not the case. :)

Comment: That's what I was assuming, but I wanted to be sure that LVL took into account the application package name when verifying the license.  On a side note, I think it might be beneficial to developers to allow a sort of "master key," so that if a user would like to purchase one, for say $10 or $20, they would have licensing for all apps using this "master key."  What are you're thoughts?

Comment: I think there are lots and lots of features that would be cool to add to Market.  I don't know what the priorities of things are with the Market team, but they certainly are not lacking in neat things they can do. :)